# Changing finite double summation $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^i f(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^k f(n+1-k).$

Tags: calculus, summation, change-of-variable

I have a double sum of the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^i f(k)
$$
and I want to change the order of the sums. From drawing some pictures I am fairly confident that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^i f(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^k f(n+1-k).
$$

Again, writing out the terms, this seems pretty clear, but I am looking for a more precise proof. I tried a change of variable, but I don't seem to be able to find something that works. So my question is: **How can I rigorously prove the above formula?**

**EDIT:** Again, I can see that the formula is true by simply writing out the terms and collecting them again. So I can see that I will $n$ terms of $f(1)$ and $n-1$ terms of $f(2)$.

What I am specifically looking for is a *rigorous* proof that the formula holds. Is there, for example, some way to do this by a change of variables? Or some way of algebraically manipulating the sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A  derivation can go as follows:

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^if(k)}
> &=\sum_{1\leq k\leq i\leq n}f(k)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=k}^nf(k)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=n-k+1}^nf(n-k+1)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^kf(n-k+1)}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^nf(n-k+1)\sum_{i=1}^k1\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=1}^nkf(n-k+1)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   where (4) is the representation claimed by the OP followed by some further simplifications.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we rewrite the index range to see the relationship between $i$ and $k$ more conveniently.
- In (2) we change the order of summation by exchanging the sums.
- In (3) we reverse the order of summation of the outer sum by setting the index $k\to n-k+1$.
- In (4) we shift the index of the inner sum $i\to i-(n-k)$ to start with $i=1$.
- In (5) we factor out $f(n-k+1)$ which does not depend on the index $i$.
- In (6) we replace the inner sum by the factor $k$.

Comment: Thank you for this!! I think your answer finally made me realize what I was confused about. It was really the second step here. But I think I have realized that there isn't a good way to make this step more precise.

Comment: @JohnDoe: You're welcome.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Many thanks for granting the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 6):

It's even better than that -- you can write it as a single sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)f(k)$$ which is the same thing as $$\sum_{k=1}^n kf(n-k+1)$$
by reindexing to sum in reverse order (use whichever form you prefer). That's because the term $f(j)$ appears in exactly your inner sums for which $i$ is at least $j$ -- that is, for the values of $i$ with $j\leq i \leq n$; there are $n-j+1$ indices in the range $j,j+1,j+2,\ldots,n$.

---

**Addendum:** To see that the double sum reduces as indicated, write out the inner sums on separate rows:
$$f(1)+\tag{row $1$}$$
$$f(1)+f(2)+\tag{row $2$}$$
$$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\tag{row $3$}$$
$$\cdots +$$
$$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\cdots+f(n)\tag{row $n$}$$
Note $f(1)$ appears in rows $1$ to $n$, $f(2)$ appears in rows $2$ to $n$; generally $f(j)$ appears in rows $j$ to $n$.

This means that there are $n-j+1$ copies of $f(j)$ in the sum. For example, $n-1+1=n$ copies of $f(1)$, $n-2+1=n-1$ copies of $f(2)$, $n-3+1=n-2$ copies of $f(3)$, etc.

So the whole sum is $nf(1)$ plus $(n-1)f(2)$ plus $(n-2)f(3)$ etc.; the generic term here is $(n-j+1)f(j)$, thus the first single sum.

To reindex, just replace $k$ in the first single summand with $n-k+1$. This simply reverses the order of summation.

Note: If an index $m$ runs from $a$ to $b$, then the index $m'\equiv b-m+a$ runs from $b$ to $a$. Since you are summing the same terms in reverse order, it should be clear that $$\sum_{m=a}^b t(m) =\sum_{m=a}^b t(b-m+a)$$

Comment: So is it the first summation that you reindex?

Comment: I'm reindexing *my* single sum, not your double sum. I reduced your double sum to my first single sum by the observation about the appearance of a given term. I'll add more, hang on a second

Comment: I guess what I am not seeing is how to make it into one sum.

Comment: That is, how do you go from $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^i f(k) $ to $\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)f(k)$? (I can see this writing out the terms and saying ..., but I am wondering about a more rigorous way.)

Comment: There, I've added more. It's really a simple counting argument. It comes down to observing that $(n-k+1)$ is the number of rows containing $f(k)$. And that's just counting the number of integers in the interval $[k,n]$.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I guess what I a m trying to say is that I already know that. I can see how to write it out and collect terms. But I end up having to write ... (dot dot dot). What I am looking for is a more rigorous proof that avoids this. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If
$s(n)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^i f(k)
$,
then this has
in the inner sum
all $k$ with
$1 \le k \le i \le n$.

This can be rearranged as
$s(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=k}^n f(k)
=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1) f(k)
$,
since the new inner sum
does not depend on $i$.

Comment: How do you rearrange?

Answer (score 0):

Given that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{i} f(k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k} f(n-k+1)$$
then one may use the generating function method to show equality.
This is seen by the following.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{i} f(k) \, t^{n} &= \sum_{n,i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{i} f(k) \, t^{n+k} \\
&= \sum_{n,i,k=1}^{\infty} f(k) \, t^{n+k+i} \\ 
&= \frac{t^2}{(1-t)^{2}} \, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k) \, t^{k}
\end{align}
For the right hand side it is easier to consider it in the form
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k} f(n-k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, f(n-k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (n-k+1) \, f(k)$$
and then take the generating function. When completed it will be shown that the left and right side generating functions are equal.

Comment: This is clearly NOT correct. Just take $n=1$ to get $f(1)$ on the left side and $f(0)$ on the right side.